# Regression report in Maven surefire-report on local box?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

We *do* have regression reports on Jenkins, where I can see the newly failing tests

I have searched on the surefire-plugin page, but could not find anything that is similar to what i see on the jenkins test report, but on my local-box.

[image]

I am looking especially for the  "(diff)" column.

Comment: Downvoters please add a comment to help us why this is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not there and I wonder if it will be supported by the mavne-surefire-plugin. Maven doesn't keep track of historic statistics, it just builds (that's its main scope). If you want such statistics, you probably need some other tool like Jenkins or maybe SonarQube

Comment: We do have this setup in Jenkins. But jenkins works on server branch and I want to test my stuff before doing a push.

Comment: My assumption is that all tests will pass. If I have my doubts, I run the test locally to see which do not succeed (and fix these first when possible). Next change the code and rerun the tests and confirm that the results are the same. In general it is best practice to fix broken tests ASAP to ensure that following commits don't break tests too.

Comment: I agree that product should have no broken test cases at any given point. But we inherited a old code base, and 30% of the test cases are failing and while trying to fix two, we are not sure if we are breaking one or two here and there...